# within json data, how to transform integer to dollar amount using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have data like this

```
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-06-12",
  "status": "pending",
  "depositDate": "2020-06-15",
  "amount": 41237
}
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-06-05",
  "status": "paid",
  "depositDate": "2020-06-08",
  "amount": 37839
}
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-04-02",
  "status": "paid",
  "depositDate": "2020-04-03",
  "amount": 67
}
```

that's being formatted with `jq` like so:

```
 request-some-api | jq '.data[] | {dateCreated: .created | strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), status: .status, depositDate: .arrival_date | strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), amount: .amount,}'
```

and I'd like to modify the `.amount` so that it displays values rather than the number of cents as a dollar amount with a decimal place...

```
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-06-12",
  "status": "pending",
  "depositDate": "2020-06-15",
  "amount": $412.37
}
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-06-05",
  "status": "paid",
  "depositDate": "2020-06-08",
  "amount": $378.39
}
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-04-02",
  "status": "paid",
  "depositDate": "2020-04-03",
  "amount": $.67
}
```

...but I haven't found any documentation about this?  Is `jq` able to do this conversion?  Even without the `$` sign but just adding the `.` between dollars and cents would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
jq '.amount = "$" + (.amount/100|tostring)' file.json
```

### Output

```
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-06-12",
  "status": "pending",
  "depositDate": "2020-06-15",
  "amount": "$412.37"
}
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-06-05",
  "status": "paid",
  "depositDate": "2020-06-08",
  "amount": "$378.39"
}
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-04-02",
  "status": "paid",
  "depositDate": "2020-04-03",
  "amount": "$0.67"
}
```

Comment: yes, to clarify, the solution in my case changes the end of my command from `amount: .amount}'` to `amount: .amount} | .amount = "$" + (.amount/100|tostring)'`.

Comment: Note edge cases, if the amount ends in 0 or 00; the formatting won't be consistent.  Dunno if that's a concern for this use case.

Comment: You should ask this to OP

Comment: You can use string interpolation to avoid the explicit call to `tostring`, and use `|=`: `'.amount |= "$\(./100)"'`

Answer (score 5):

Your required output looks malformed; I'd expect "amount" to become a string value.

You can do this by adding a $ to the beginning, then dividing the amount by 100 and converting to a string

eg

```
jq '.amount = "$" + (.amount/100|tostring)'
```

Doing that on your test file we can see the 3 `amount` lines get converted to:

```
"amount": "$412.37"
"amount": "$378.39"
"amount": "$0.67"
```

However this has a couple of odd cases, which may (or may not) matter.  If the amount ends in zero (eg 41230) then it will display as "$412.3". Similarly if it's whole dollars (41200) then it'll display was "$412".

I'm not sure `jq` has a simple way of handling these so I added a couple of tests:

```
jq '.amount = "$" + (.amount/100|tostring) + (if .amount%100 == 0 then ".0" else "" end ) + (if .amount%10 ==0 then "0" else "" end)'
```

There may be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ jq '.amount |= "$" + (./100 | tostring | ltrimstr("0"))' file
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-06-12",
  "status": "pending",
  "depositDate": "2020-06-15",
  "amount": "$412.37"
}
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-06-05",
  "status": "paid",
  "depositDate": "2020-06-08",
  "amount": "$378.39"
}
{
  "dateCreated": "2020-04-02",
  "status": "paid",
  "depositDate": "2020-04-03",
  "amount": "$.67"
}
```

This converts the `amount` key's value to a string after dividing it by 100.  It then trims off the leading zero if present before prepending a `$` to the string.